# Build failed with exception Could not resolve com.otaliastudios:transcoder:0.9.1

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.otaliastudios:transcoder:0.9.1.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :video_compress
> > Could not resolve com.otaliastudios:transcoder:0.9.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/otaliastudios/transcoder/0.9.1/transcoder-0.9.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/otaliastudios/transcoder/0.9.1/transcoder-0.9.1.pom'.
> > storage.googleapis.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
> > Could not resolve com.otaliastudios:transcoder:0.9.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/otaliastudios/transcoder/0.9.1/transcoder-0.9.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/otaliastudios/transcoder/0.9.1/transcoder-0.9.1.pom'.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error, and as it states the problem seems to be that that specific version of the transcoder lib is not available on maven or google repos.

With a rapid google search I found this webpage which shows that it's available on the jcenter repository. So, just by adding jcenter() to the android/build.gradle file I was able to solve the issue. It should be looks similar to this:

```
 allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```